# ion-nav-buttons not showing on right side

Tags: html, css, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on a project and i have a problem.
I have this in `index.html`

```
<ion-side-menus>
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-dark nav-title-slide-ios7">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
                <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
            </ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view animation="slide-right-left"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-side-menu side="right">
      ......
    </ion-side-menu>

</ion-side-menus>
```

In another `.html` file i have this:

```
<ion-view>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button menu-toggle="right" class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons> 

  <ion-content class="has-header" padding="true">
       <h1 style="text-align: center;">Home Page</h1>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The problem is that the navicon button is not showing up as expected:
[image: screenshot with the problem]

I have tried the app on my phone and it's the same as the in the picture.

What might be the problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem!

I was overwriting some buttons style in other CSS.